# Fluent NHibernate many-to-many relationship on existing database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am mapping an existing database using Fluent NHibernate and have encountered a problem when trying to populate many-to-many collections. The database itself is not set up correctly using foreign keys, here is a simplified example of the problem I'm having.

Tables:

1. Users
2. Groups
3. UsersInGroups

---

### Entity Classes:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual long UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public virtual long GroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserInGroup
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    #region Fluent NHibernate Composite Key Overrides

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var compare = obj as UserInGroup;

        if (compare == null)
            return false;

        return User.UserID == compare.User.UserID &&
               Group.GroupID == compare.Group.GroupID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (User.UserID + "|" + Group.GroupID).GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

### Mapping Classes:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserID, "UserID").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Groups).Table("UsersInGroups")
                                    .ParentKeyColumn("GroupID")
                                    .ChildKeyColumn("UserID")
                                    .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Table("Groups");
        Id(x => x.GroupID, "GroupID").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users).Table("UsersInGroups")
                                   .ParentKeyColumn("UserID")
                                   .ChildKeyColumn("GroupID")
                                   .Inverse();
    }
}

public class UserInGroupMap : ClassMap<UserInGroup>
{
    public UserInGroupMap()
    {
        Table("UsersInGroups");

        CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.User, "UserID")
                     .KeyReference(x => x.Group, "GroupID");
    }
}
```

---

In my configuration I have eager loading enabled, the HasMany relationships seem to be working okay but the HasManyToMany relationships are returning an empty collection. I have tried a few different combinations of Cascade.All() and Inverse on the collections all with no success. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try invert the `ParentKeyColumn` and `ChildKeyColumn` in both mappings.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria this was what was causing the issue. I can't believe I overlooked it. I thought that the `ParentKeyColumn` would map to the list of Entities and not the child. Thank you very much

Comment: Afaik cascading is for saves/updates.. not reads. Glad you got it sorted though.

Answer (score 2):

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Users).Table("UsersInGroups")
                           .ParentKeyColumn("UserID")
                           .ChildKeyColumn("GroupID")
                           .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Users).Table("UsersInGroups") 
      .ParentKeyColumn("GroupID")
      .ChildKeyColumn("UserID")
      .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Please give more explanation as to why your answer answers the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!